# Show Bundle & Grouped Product Options On Product List Page

Tags: magento

I am trying to show the options of a Bundle Product and a Grouped product in the product list page.

I have found a script on the internet to show configurable products but I am struggling to find one on a Bundle and Grouped.

Basically I want it to show the options exactly the same as it does as if I was viewing the actual products page.

Thanks

Comment: have you found a solution on this?

Answer (score 1):

Try with below code

1 ) put these three below function in your list.php file if you have overwrite it, otherwise first overwrite that file Mage/Catalog/Block?Product/List.php

```
protected function _getProduct($sku)
    {
         $_productId = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($sku);
         if($_productId)
         {
            return Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_productId);    
         }
         return null;
    } 

    public function getAssociatedProducts($sku)
    {
        $_product = $this->_getProduct($sku);
        $simpleProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($_product);
        return $simpleProducts;
    }

    /**
     * Set preconfigured values to grouped associated products
     *
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Grouped
     */
    public function setPreconfiguredValue($sku) {
        $_product = $this->_getProduct($sku);
        $configValues = $_product->getPreconfiguredValues()->getSuperGroup();
        if (is_array($configValues)) {
            $associatedProducts = $this->getAssociatedProducts($sku);
            foreach ($associatedProducts as $item) {
                if (isset($configValues[$item->getId()])) {
                    $item->setQty($configValues[$item->getId()]);
                }
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

2 ) put below code in your list.phtml file design/frontend/default/default/template/catelog/product/list.phtml after this line

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>

<?php if($_product->getTypeId() == 'grouped'){ ?>
                 <?php $this->setPreconfiguredValue($_product->getSku()); ?> 
                 <?php $_associatedProducts = $this->getAssociatedProducts($_product->getSku()); ?>
                 <?php $_hasAssociatedProducts = count($_associatedProducts) > 0; ?>
                 <table class="data-table grouped-items-table" id="super-product-table">
                    <col />
                    <col />
                    <col width="1" />
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th><?php echo $this->__('Name') ?></th>
                            <?php if ($this->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)): ?>
                            <th class="a-right"><?php echo $this->__('Price') ?></th>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php if ($_hasAssociatedProducts): ?>
                    <?php foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_item): ?>
                        <?php $_finalPriceInclTax = $this->helper('tax')->getPrice($_item, $_item->getFinalPrice(), true) ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?></td>
                            <?php if ($this->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)): ?>
                            <td class="a-right">
                                <?php if ($this->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)): ?>
                                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true) ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </td>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                       <tr>
                           <td colspan="<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>4<?php else : ?>3<?php endif; ?>"><?php echo $this->__('No options of this product are available.') ?></td>
                       </tr>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('super-product-table')</script>
               <?php  }  ?>
```

3 )[image]

May be this help for you !
Note: this code only working for grouped products